# Portfolio NavBar : HTML, CSS, FLEXBOX

Tags: html, css

So, This is a very specific problem:

- I want you to run the code, and open it in a full window.
- Now please inspect the following code, and toggle the responsive mode.
- Now, change the dimensions to something small, until you can see a hamburger.
- Now click the hamburger. Works fine?
- Now close the hamburger.
- Scroll until the end of the page, in this mobile view.
- Now try opening the hamburger. Most probably it won't work.
- Now scroll to about just below the top of the page in the responsive mobile view. Here open the hamburger. You should be able to see a glitched out half menu like included in the image.

[image: half glitched menu]

I don't know why or how this is happening. Could someone please reslove this? Any help will be appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
    />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;800&family=Quicksand:wght@300&family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap");

@font-face {
  font-family: AstroSpace;
  src: url(/fonts/AstroSpace.ttf);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #212c3b;
}

header {
  background-color: #141b25;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  height: 90px;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900  ;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: "Roboto  ", sans-serif;
}

.navlinks {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navlinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.navlinks li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navlinks li a:hover {
  color: #7ebcb9;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7ebcb9;
}

li a.contact {
  background-color: #00adb5;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a.contact:hover {
  background-color: #047e85;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

.menu-btn {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navlinks {
    top: 90px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    right: -100%;
    background: #222831;
  }

  .navlinks li {
    display: block;
  }

  .navlinks li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .navlinks li a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  #check:checked ~ .navlinks {
    right: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn:focus {
    color: blue;
  }
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
        <label for="check" class="menu-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">Nikita Gada</a>
        <ul class="navlinks">
          <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur sapiente, distinctio ipsam rem eos ipsum ea praesentium repellat animi maxime adipisci exercitationem, vel facere? Commodi deserunt minima quas accusantium aliquid tenetur repudiandae quam dolor culpa aperiam voluptates id, quia nobis facilis ipsum perferendis blanditiis nemo sint doloribus hic? Veniam culpa aperiam sunt harum et! Ex eaque incidunt nostrum error corrupti ratione consequuntur obcaecati quaerat, beatae id praesentium quibusdam laborum ipsam dolorum voluptates nemo, omnis quia dolorem quos! Similique labore quos placeat minus illo doloribus iste est nisi necessitatibus, illum totam, inventore incidunt omnis molestiae corporis exercitationem quibusdam ipsum ullam excepturi. Ea exercitationem amet omnis sunt id sed, nobis perspiciatis quidem, tempore asperiores recusandae deserunt aut nihil, aperiam ducimus libero iste nisi debitis nulla voluptates quos nesciunt. Eligendi obcaecati a, nisi porro unde id explicabo! Asperiores vel omnis non alias debitis distinctio, minima nostrum architecto nulla iusto, qui sed accusamus, excepturi ratione? Dolorem doloremque quo autem velit iste quis dolores. Rem earum enim ducimus eaque animi repellendus voluptates debitis consequuntur assumenda autem amet, aperiam culpa inventore sed? Pariatur placeat nesciunt voluptatibus earum cupiditate fuga optio quia sunt suscipit voluptatum delectus facilis nihil ut, nemo itaque, voluptatem nulla consequatur aspernatur consequuntur libero, magnam sequi nobis incidunt asperiores? Sed aspernatur corporis fugiat, animi illum accusantium repellendus laudantium voluptate unde a modi nesciunt non sequi, reprehenderit asperiores doloremque eum necessitatibus quibusdam. A voluptate beatae perferendis natus, cupiditate nihil illo esse vero blanditiis voluptatibus tempore repellat unde numquam quam dignissimos laborum ipsam consectetur minus corrupti quasi! Molestias unde velit, dolor ullam iure debitis maiores et, rem facilis tempore odio, labore omnis aspernatur tempora sunt ratione quos cumque accusantium harum voluptatum. Consequatur aspernatur maxime nobis veritatis quasi provident perferendis veniam dolores nostrum deleniti, consequuntur reprehenderit amet excepturi, quae libero id dolorum voluptatibus assumenda praesentium, quibusdam est sint. Dignissimos fugiat ducimus minima alias dicta sit, excepturi maxime, maiores velit recusandae esse sed ad voluptatibus repudiandae iure quaerat soluta ab sequi officiis id aut. Ipsum error sit vel rerum exercitationem. Nulla ducimus nesciunt incidunt pariatur, quo nihil fugit ipsa dolores maxime eum reiciendis, maiores aliquam quas consequuntur quaerat vel! Ipsum error in itaque placeat accusantium autem, quos, necessitatibus dolores dignissimos perferendis tempora eligendi nobis quis quia tempore, rerum distinctio consectetur? Odit, quisquam a modi atque fugiat provident iste expedita voluptatem eveniet unde molestiae eos, nobis sunt est repudiandae obcaecati voluptatibus dolorum consectetur autem. Neque quidem, modi saepe quibusdam voluptatibus iste distinctio, eum eligendi aliquid cum nisi. Magnam, nulla consequuntur aliquid dolorem maiores odio placeat sint molestiae, quis, tenetur labore nemo! Ipsum reprehenderit ex dolorum nostrum cupiditate, dolore molestias iure eos a doloremque nisi possimus ducimus odio quo! Beatae non necessitatibus fuga accusamus, 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set a `top : 80px` on your `navlinks` in your `@media (max-width: 800px)` and it seems to be working. Take a look.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
    />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;800&family=Quicksand:wght@300&family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap");

@font-face {
  font-family: AstroSpace;
  src: url(/fonts/AstroSpace.ttf);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #212c3b;
}

header {
  background-color: #141b25;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  height: 90px;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900  ;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: "Roboto  ", sans-serif;
}

.navlinks {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navlinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.navlinks li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navlinks li a:hover {
  color: #7ebcb9;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7ebcb9;
}

li a.contact {
  background-color: #00adb5;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a.contact:hover {
  background-color: #047e85;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

.menu-btn {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navlinks {
    position: fixed;
    /* line I added */
    top:90px;;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    right: -100%;
    background: #222831;
  }

  .navlinks li {
    display: block;
  }

  .navlinks li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .navlinks li a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  #check:checked ~ .navlinks {
    right: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn:focus {
    color: blue;
  }
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
        <label for="check" class="menu-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">Nikita Gada</a>
        <ul class="navlinks">
          <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur sapiente, distinctio ipsam rem eos ipsum ea praesentium repellat animi maxime adipisci exercitationem, vel facere? Commodi deserunt minima quas accusantium aliquid tenetur repudiandae quam dolor culpa aperiam voluptates id, quia nobis facilis ipsum perferendis blanditiis nemo sint doloribus hic? Veniam culpa aperiam sunt harum et! Ex eaque incidunt nostrum error corrupti ratione consequuntur obcaecati quaerat, beatae id praesentium quibusdam laborum ipsam dolorum voluptates nemo, omnis quia dolorem quos! Similique labore quos placeat minus illo doloribus iste est nisi necessitatibus, illum totam, inventore incidunt omnis molestiae corporis exercitationem quibusdam ipsum ullam excepturi. Ea exercitationem amet omnis sunt id sed, nobis perspiciatis quidem, tempore asperiores recusandae deserunt aut nihil, aperiam ducimus libero iste nisi debitis nulla voluptates quos nesciunt. Eligendi obcaecati a, nisi porro unde id explicabo! Asperiores vel omnis non alias debitis distinctio, minima nostrum architecto nulla iusto, qui sed accusamus, excepturi ratione? Dolorem doloremque quo autem velit iste quis dolores. Rem earum enim ducimus eaque animi repellendus voluptates debitis consequuntur assumenda autem amet, aperiam culpa inventore sed? Pariatur placeat nesciunt voluptatibus earum cupiditate fuga optio quia sunt suscipit voluptatum delectus facilis nihil ut, nemo itaque, voluptatem nulla consequatur aspernatur consequuntur libero, magnam sequi nobis incidunt asperiores? Sed aspernatur corporis fugiat, animi illum accusantium repellendus laudantium voluptate unde a modi nesciunt non sequi, reprehenderit asperiores doloremque eum necessitatibus quibusdam. A voluptate beatae perferendis natus, cupiditate nihil illo esse vero blanditiis voluptatibus tempore repellat unde numquam quam dignissimos laborum ipsam consectetur minus corrupti quasi! Molestias unde velit, dolor ullam iure debitis maiores et, rem facilis tempore odio, labore omnis aspernatur tempora sunt ratione quos cumque accusantium harum voluptatum. Consequatur aspernatur maxime nobis veritatis quasi provident perferendis veniam dolores nostrum deleniti, consequuntur reprehenderit amet excepturi, quae libero id dolorum voluptatibus assumenda praesentium, quibusdam est sint. Dignissimos fugiat ducimus minima alias dicta sit, excepturi maxime, maiores velit recusandae esse sed ad voluptatibus repudiandae iure quaerat soluta ab sequi officiis id aut. Ipsum error sit vel rerum exercitationem. Nulla ducimus nesciunt incidunt pariatur, quo nihil fugit ipsa dolores maxime eum reiciendis, maiores aliquam quas consequuntur quaerat vel! Ipsum error in itaque placeat accusantium autem, quos, necessitatibus dolores dignissimos perferendis tempora eligendi nobis quis quia tempore, rerum distinctio consectetur? Odit, quisquam a modi atque fugiat provident iste expedita voluptatem eveniet unde molestiae eos, nobis sunt est repudiandae obcaecati voluptatibus dolorum consectetur autem. Neque quidem, modi saepe quibusdam voluptatibus iste distinctio, eum eligendi aliquid cum nisi. Magnam, nulla consequuntur aliquid dolorem maiores odio placeat sint molestiae, quis, tenetur labore nemo! Ipsum reprehenderit ex dolorum nostrum cupiditate, dolore molestias iure eos a doloremque nisi possimus ducimus odio quo! Beatae non necessitatibus fuga accusamus, 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, The problem is you never define the `top` property of the `.navlinks`. Please check the snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
    />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;800&family=Quicksand:wght@300&family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap");

@font-face {
  font-family: AstroSpace;
  src: url(/fonts/AstroSpace.ttf);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #212c3b;
}

header {
  background-color: #141b25;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  height: 90px;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900  ;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: "Roboto  ", sans-serif;
}

.navlinks {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navlinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.navlinks li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navlinks li a:hover {
  color: #7ebcb9;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7ebcb9;
}

li a.contact {
  background-color: #00adb5;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a.contact:hover {
  background-color: #047e85;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

.menu-btn {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navlinks {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    right: -100%;
    background: #222831;
    top: 90px;
  }

  .navlinks li {
    display: block;
  }

  .navlinks li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .navlinks li a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  #check:checked ~ .navlinks {
    right: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn:focus {
    color: blue;
  }
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
        <label for="check" class="menu-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">Nikita Gada</a>
        <ul class="navlinks">
          <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur sapiente, distinctio ipsam rem eos ipsum ea praesentium repellat animi maxime adipisci exercitationem, vel facere? Commodi deserunt minima quas accusantium aliquid tenetur repudiandae quam dolor culpa aperiam voluptates id, quia nobis facilis ipsum perferendis blanditiis nemo sint doloribus hic? Veniam culpa aperiam sunt harum et! Ex eaque incidunt nostrum error corrupti ratione consequuntur obcaecati quaerat, beatae id praesentium quibusdam laborum ipsam dolorum voluptates nemo, omnis quia dolorem quos! Similique labore quos placeat minus illo doloribus iste est nisi necessitatibus, illum totam, inventore incidunt omnis molestiae corporis exercitationem quibusdam ipsum ullam excepturi. Ea exercitationem amet omnis sunt id sed, nobis perspiciatis quidem, tempore asperiores recusandae deserunt aut nihil, aperiam ducimus libero iste nisi debitis nulla voluptates quos nesciunt. Eligendi obcaecati a, nisi porro unde id explicabo! Asperiores vel omnis non alias debitis distinctio, minima nostrum architecto nulla iusto, qui sed accusamus, excepturi ratione? Dolorem doloremque quo autem velit iste quis dolores. Rem earum enim ducimus eaque animi repellendus voluptates debitis consequuntur assumenda autem amet, aperiam culpa inventore sed? Pariatur placeat nesciunt voluptatibus earum cupiditate fuga optio quia sunt suscipit voluptatum delectus facilis nihil ut, nemo itaque, voluptatem nulla consequatur aspernatur consequuntur libero, magnam sequi nobis incidunt asperiores? Sed aspernatur corporis fugiat, animi illum accusantium repellendus laudantium voluptate unde a modi nesciunt non sequi, reprehenderit asperiores doloremque eum necessitatibus quibusdam. A voluptate beatae perferendis natus, cupiditate nihil illo esse vero blanditiis voluptatibus tempore repellat unde numquam quam dignissimos laborum ipsam consectetur minus corrupti quasi! Molestias unde velit, dolor ullam iure debitis maiores et, rem facilis tempore odio, labore omnis aspernatur tempora sunt ratione quos cumque accusantium harum voluptatum. Consequatur aspernatur maxime nobis veritatis quasi provident perferendis veniam dolores nostrum deleniti, consequuntur reprehenderit amet excepturi, quae libero id dolorum voluptatibus assumenda praesentium, quibusdam est sint. Dignissimos fugiat ducimus minima alias dicta sit, excepturi maxime, maiores velit recusandae esse sed ad voluptatibus repudiandae iure quaerat soluta ab sequi officiis id aut. Ipsum error sit vel rerum exercitationem. Nulla ducimus nesciunt incidunt pariatur, quo nihil fugit ipsa dolores maxime eum reiciendis, maiores aliquam quas consequuntur quaerat vel! Ipsum error in itaque placeat accusantium autem, quos, necessitatibus dolores dignissimos perferendis tempora eligendi nobis quis quia tempore, rerum distinctio consectetur? Odit, quisquam a modi atque fugiat provident iste expedita voluptatem eveniet unde molestiae eos, nobis sunt est repudiandae obcaecati voluptatibus dolorum consectetur autem. Neque quidem, modi saepe quibusdam voluptatibus iste distinctio, eum eligendi aliquid cum nisi. Magnam, nulla consequuntur aliquid dolorem maiores odio placeat sint molestiae, quis, tenetur labore nemo! Ipsum reprehenderit ex dolorum nostrum cupiditate, dolore molestias iure eos a doloremque nisi possimus ducimus odio quo! Beatae non necessitatibus fuga accusamus, 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, altho my job is already done, since somebody else gave an answer

Answer (score 0):

just add `top: 90px;` to `@media (max-width: 800px) { .navlinks {top: 90px;}}`

```css
<style>

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap");

@font-face {
  font-family: AstroSpace;
  src: url(/fonts/AstroSpace.ttf);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #212c3b;
}

header {
  background-color: #141b25;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  height: 90px;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900  ;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: "Roboto  ", sans-serif;
}

.navlinks {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navlinks li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.navlinks li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navlinks li a:hover {
  color: #7ebcb9;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #7ebcb9;
}

li a.contact {
  background-color: #00adb5;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  border-bottom: none;
}

li a.contact:hover {
  background-color: #047e85;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

.menu-btn {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navlinks {
    position: fixed;
    top: 90px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    right: -100%;
    background: #222831;
  }

  .navlinks li {
    display: block;
  }

  .navlinks li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .navlinks li a:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  #check:checked ~ .navlinks {
    right: 0;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .logo {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .menu-btn:focus {
    color: blue;
  }
}
    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Responsive Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"
    />

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;800&family=Quicksand:wght@300&family=Roboto:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
        <label for="check" class="menu-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </label>
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">Nikita Gada</a>
        <ul class="navlinks">
          <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur sapiente, distinctio ipsam rem eos ipsum ea praesentium repellat animi maxime adipisci exercitationem, vel facere? Commodi deserunt minima quas accusantium aliquid tenetur repudiandae quam dolor culpa aperiam voluptates id, quia nobis facilis ipsum perferendis blanditiis nemo sint doloribus hic? Veniam culpa aperiam sunt harum et! Ex eaque incidunt nostrum error corrupti ratione consequuntur obcaecati quaerat, beatae id praesentium quibusdam laborum ipsam dolorum voluptates nemo, omnis quia dolorem quos! Similique labore quos placeat minus illo doloribus iste est nisi necessitatibus, illum totam, inventore incidunt omnis molestiae corporis exercitationem quibusdam ipsum ullam excepturi. Ea exercitationem amet omnis sunt id sed, nobis perspiciatis quidem, tempore asperiores recusandae deserunt aut nihil, aperiam ducimus libero iste nisi debitis nulla voluptates quos nesciunt. Eligendi obcaecati a, nisi porro unde id explicabo! Asperiores vel omnis non alias debitis distinctio, minima nostrum architecto nulla iusto, qui sed accusamus, excepturi ratione? Dolorem doloremque quo autem velit iste quis dolores. Rem earum enim ducimus eaque animi repellendus voluptates debitis consequuntur assumenda autem amet, aperiam culpa inventore sed? Pariatur placeat nesciunt voluptatibus earum cupiditate fuga optio quia sunt suscipit voluptatum delectus facilis nihil ut, nemo itaque, voluptatem nulla consequatur aspernatur consequuntur libero, magnam sequi nobis incidunt asperiores? Sed aspernatur corporis fugiat, animi illum accusantium repellendus laudantium voluptate unde a modi nesciunt non sequi, reprehenderit asperiores doloremque eum necessitatibus quibusdam. A voluptate beatae perferendis natus, cupiditate nihil illo esse vero blanditiis voluptatibus tempore repellat unde numquam quam dignissimos laborum ipsam consectetur minus corrupti quasi! Molestias unde velit, dolor ullam iure debitis maiores et, rem facilis tempore odio, labore omnis aspernatur tempora sunt ratione quos cumque accusantium harum voluptatum. Consequatur aspernatur maxime nobis veritatis quasi provident perferendis veniam dolores nostrum deleniti, consequuntur reprehenderit amet excepturi, quae libero id dolorum voluptatibus assumenda praesentium, quibusdam est sint. Dignissimos fugiat ducimus minima alias dicta sit, excepturi maxime, maiores velit recusandae esse sed ad voluptatibus repudiandae iure quaerat soluta ab sequi officiis id aut. Ipsum error sit vel rerum exercitationem. Nulla ducimus nesciunt incidunt pariatur, quo nihil fugit ipsa dolores maxime eum reiciendis, maiores aliquam quas consequuntur quaerat vel! Ipsum error in itaque placeat accusantium autem, quos, necessitatibus dolores dignissimos perferendis tempora eligendi nobis quis quia tempore, rerum distinctio consectetur? Odit, quisquam a modi atque fugiat provident iste expedita voluptatem eveniet unde molestiae eos, nobis sunt est repudiandae obcaecati voluptatibus dolorum consectetur autem. Neque quidem, modi saepe quibusdam voluptatibus iste distinctio, eum eligendi aliquid cum nisi. Magnam, nulla consequuntur aliquid dolorem maiores odio placeat sint molestiae, quis, tenetur labore nemo! Ipsum reprehenderit ex dolorum nostrum cupiditate, dolore molestias iure eos a doloremque nisi possimus ducimus odio quo! Beatae non necessitatibus fuga accusamus, 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you altho i have already recieved the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Please add CSS property in .navlink class. i have added " top:90px; " in this class. when applying position fixed to any element add specific two side values like left and top, Or top and right, Or right and bottom, Or left and bottom.

```
.navlinks {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    right: -100%;
    top: 90px;
    background: #222831;
}
```

Comment: ty, but i already got the answer